# jQuery doesn't work in my php snippet

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following snippet to prevent the purchase of products by displaying a text and hiding the "proceed to checkout" button. The text part works great but the jQuery part  doesn't i don't know why. Any ideas ?
Thanks.

```
function wc_minimum_order_amount_premium() {

 $minimum = 8;

  if ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_count < $minimum ) {

  $draught_links = array();

  foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {

      $_product = $values['data'];

      $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

      foreach ($terms as $term) {
          $draught_links[] = $term->name;
      }   

  }

  if (in_array("PREMIUM", $draught_links)){
      $on_draught = true;
  }else{
      $on_draught = false;
  }

  if( is_cart() ) {

      if($on_draught){

          wc_print_notice( 
              sprintf( 'Vous devez avoir un minimum de %s pour finaliser cette commande, vous en avez %s au total.' , 
                   $minimum , 
                   WC()->cart->cart_contents_count
              ), 'error' 
          );

          echo '<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery( ".wc-proceed-to-checkout" ).css("display", "none");</script>';

      }

  } else {

      if($on_draught){

          wc_add_notice( 
              sprintf( 'Vous devez avoir un minimum de %s pour finaliser cette commande, vous en avez %s au total.' , 
                  $minimum , 
                  WC()->cart->cart_contents_count
              ), 'error' 
          );

          echo '<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery( ".wc-proceed-to-checkout" ).css("display", "none");</script>';

      }

  }
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery doesn't work? Are you getting any errors? Anyways if it is purely related to jQuery, you better ask at StackOverflow as pure HTML/CSS/jQuery specific questions are off-topic here

Comment: No errors but my script has no effect even if its properly called in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this not perfect way to write inline java script , write java script into document ready event

```
jQuerydocument ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".wc-proceed-to-checkout" ).css("display", "none");
});
```